# Boolean equivalence

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I use `ISNULL` and `COALESCE` in `ON` clauses quite regularly but have read that this can cause optimization problems as indexes might not get used.

I currently have the following:

```
FROM  dbo.tb_xxx x
      INNER JOIN dbo.tb_yyy y ON        
        x.Client    = COALESCE(y.Client, x.Client) AND
        x.Prod  = COALESCE(y.Prod, x.Prod)
```

...I've converted to the following...

```
FROM   dbo.tb_xxx x
       INNER JOIN dbo.tb_yyy y ON       
        x.Client    = y.Client AND
        x.Prod      = y.Prod 
        OR y.Client IS NULL
        OR y.Prod IS NULL
```

Are these equivalent?
If not, then why not?

---

**EDIT**
I'm not 100% that it might impact performance but recently I read a text by Itzik Ben-Gan which stated that using predicates like `COALESCE(T1.col1,-1) = COALESCE(T2.col1,-1)` when joining sets of data can impact performance as the manipulation of col1 will mean that the data is re-built and existing indexes on col1 will not get used. This is the concept of "sargability".

Rather than using this match predicate
`COALESCE(T1.col1,-1) = COALESCE(T2.col1,-1)`
He suggests this
`T1.col1 = T2.col1 OR (T1.col1 IS NULL AND T2.col1 IS NULL)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are not.

What you've written is equivalent to

```
 (x.Client    = y.Client AND x.Prod      = y.Prod)
    OR (y.Client IS NULL)
    OR (y.Prod IS NULL)
```

You need

```
 (x.Client    = y.Client OR y.Client IS NULL)
AND
( x.Prod      = y.Prod  OR y.Prod IS NULL)
```

And I'm not sure that would be any better than the original.

On the subject of performance, on SQL Server, `ISNULL` often performs better than `COALESCE`, but the latter is ANSI compliant if that is important to you.

So it seems to me, you're may be trying to do a left join?

```
 FROM   dbo.tb_xxx x
 LEFT JOIN dbo.tb_yyy y ON       
    x.Client    = y.Client AND
    x.Prod      = y.Prod
```

Comment: +1 it does look like a left join except for it will not accept rows where x.Client or x.Prod is null (which would be accepted in a left join). Also one value could match while the other doesn't

Comment: ...+1 thanks. COALESCE is my default as it seems to deal with type issues better.

Comment: ...have edited OP with a better explanation of what I recently read that has prompted my conversion of this `ON` clasue

Comment: The best way to determine performance is probably to experiment with the data in your own specific situation. For example, using an OR in a filter normally brings its own performance issues!

Comment: I will check the alternative execution plans

Comment: ...the execution plan for the original `ISNULL` version is very simple compared to the new version but the new version spends 24% cost on one clustered index scan + 73% on a different index seek; whereas the old version has 21% on a Nested Loops compared to the new version which only has 4% on Nested Loops ...so maybe even though it is a more complicated plan it might be more efficient. As you can tell my experience with execution plans is limited!

Comment: Your first question should be - is performance a problem here? If not, then you should probably go for the option that most clearly expresses your intentions.

Comment: +1: Note: though `ISNULL` is faster than `COALESCE` the difference is slight and does not affect whether an expression is SARG-able.  Additionally, many prefer `COALESCE` because it is Standard SQL and works unchanged on other platforms.